# Example of QGIS for landscape management and maintenance plans?

Tags: qgis, landscape, maintenance

I'm writing about landscape management and maintenance plans, and that most of them are in a Word file with perhaps a table of tasks, as opposed to a smart document such as a QGIS file with a linked database of tasks.

A plan would include a list of all tasks that might need to be undertaken, and then a table showing when each task should take place.

Writing it in Word means there is no way to filter tasks, such as only showing tasks that are required in week 10, or all tasks for a specific location.

My suspicion is that this would be far better in QGIS, showing areas in plan and a filterable range of tasks associated with each area that can be exported as worksheets for site staff.

Does anyone know of an example of something similar? It could be habitat management or landscape management.

Comment: I use QGIS to generate maps for tree maintenance programs, using symbology and map atlases to inform what work needs to be done where, with what priority. You can also add dynamic tables to the maps to list what needs to be done in each area

Comment: thank you, that sounds exactly what I was thinking of. Would you be happy to share a screen shot? I'd be really interested to see how it looks.  I won't use anything in the book without your full permission

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely consider organizing these data and tasks into a **database**, creating sites (polygons) with unique SITE_ID's, and then generating tasks associated to those SITE_ID's with TASK_ID's, potentially START_TIME and END_TIME columns, etc.

From there, it will likely require some development to make QGIS the the 'GUI' to this system, but the same database could also be turned into a web application that both visualizes and filters tasks based on spatial extent and time filters, and generating exports of tasks based on those criteria.

Comment: Thank you - I love the idea of a web application, as that could be used on site for those carrying out the work, or to print work sheets for that day's tasks.  it gives one central point too, so there is no issue with revisions.

Comment: The way that different web frameworks hook up to databases will be of great benefit to you... combined with a spatial component like Leaflet.js